# IDA Pro doesnt read updated exe

Tags: ida

When I change/update the disassembled exe (like when I rebuild it) then IDA doesn't update the exe.

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
Adi.

Answer (score 1):

`IDA` loads the file once and creates its DB at load time. After that, it doesn't need the original file, and it has no possibility to detect changes on the loaded file. If you want to see updated changes - you need to load the file again in `IDA`.

Comment: The point is that i delete all the database files and load the executable from scratch and the problem persists!

Comment: That sounds like an error on your part. Double-check the timestamps on the files you're trying to load to ensure that they have actually been generated since you last built them.

Comment: Yes, the newly built exes have new timestamps, but IDA loads old versions.:-(

Comment: In fact, there is “reload file” option which tries to update the IDB from the file on disk, but it may not work properly if the changes were too extensive.

Comment: Wow, which option?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
The exe UPDATES indeed. I was just looking for an answer for a different kind of problem. When I compile 1) "if" branches disappear when not used 2) functions are collapsed and you can't see them in IDA. So sorry for wrong question and I should seek further :-)

Best regards,
Adi

Comment: Sounds like the optimizer kicking in. Ask your compiler (you don't say which one) to turn off optimization. In this case unused branches should still become code visible in the disassembly.